# Android AudioManager getParameters and setParameters functions

Tags: android, audio, android-audiomanager

It appears that the documentation for the setParameters function is very poor:
"Sets a variable number of parameter values to audio hardware."

As described in:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setParameters%28java.lang.String%29

But which keys and values? does somebody know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These parameters are mostly used by OEMs. Setting the parameter a certain way can change how the audio sounds. Unfortunately, I can't go into details/specifics.

For general purpose, I find no use of these APIs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: How can I find the available values for the device? Is there a website that gathers them? Maybe a website for each? Or for each OEM ? Can this help with call recording? I believe this app might use them: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lb.lwp_plus&hl=en

Comment: Most of the values would be private. I'm sure you've seen use cases like https://blog.csdn.net/ch853199769/article/details/77838713 or https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-android/issues/230.

As far as I know, none of the values allowed an app to record calls without user permission. In the past, they had to do with routing / audio quality, forcing volume, etc. You would need system permission to do that. I don't work on the OEM side anymore so I also don't know if there have been recent changes.